# Content Database(Size) when using RBS

Tags: database, content-database, rbs, size

When using RBS what is the total size limit that can be uploaded to SharePoint?

Is there any size limitation concerning the data?

When I right click on my content database that enable RBS it shows me the size of the content database plus the size of the RBS file, is this size has the limit (200GB) or the size of the ".MDF" file only (excluding the size of RBS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When using RBS what is the total size limit that can be uploaded to SharePoint?** 
**Is there any size limitation concerning the data?**

Per file: The absolute maximum size per file that can be uploaded is 2GB - RBS does not change this.

Per content db: The standard 200GB (on SP2010 and 2013) or 100GB (on SP2007) includes both the data within the SQL db (i.e. mdf files) and externalized files:
"If you are using Remote BLOB Storage (RBS), the total volume of remote BLOB storage and metadata in the content database must not exceed the 200GB limit."

Ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

**When I right click on my content database that enable RBS it shows me the size of the content database plus the size of the RBS file, is this size has the limit (200GB) or the size of the ".MDF" file only (excluding the size of RBS)**

Typically when right clicking content databases and viewing the size - via properties - this will only be the size of the MDFs and LDFs - not the externalized files.

The standard way to view the total size of external files via T-SQL is with a command such as:
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH()) FROM ;

Although you could perhaps run this command on a content db and get away with it, it would not be recommended.

Ideally just view the total size via Windows Explorer or if you're using a third party provider such as AvePoint/Metalogix then the total externalized data should be visible through their UIs.

HTH.